# Building a bazel 3rd party from a cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, bazel

I need to integrate a bazel C++ project as part of a cmake project.
I have no experience with cmake and haven't found how I could do so.

The bazel output is a shared library that will get linked to the cmake project.